# RFM9x LoRa Radio code will compile with Uno but not Nano Every

Tags: arduino-nano-every

I have code involving the use of an Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout v3 and an Adafruit RFM95W LoRa Radio that will compile with an Uno Rev3 but not with a Nano Every. The code I'm using comes almost directly from the examples provided by Arduino. I tried just the GPS code using the GPS_SoftwareSerial_Parsing test from Arduino and that worked, but I when I try using the Feather9x_TX code from Arduino it does not and I am not sure why. I am new to using Arduinos and have little experience with coding. I have attempted to search my error messages but have not been able to really find any answers so any help would be useful.

Here's the code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

#define RFM95_CS 9
#define RFM95_RST 8
#define RFM95_INT 2

// Change to 434.0 or other frequency, must match RX's freq!
#define RF95_FREQ 915.0

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(1);
  }

  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Feather LoRa TX Test!");

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);

  while (!rf95.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
    Serial.println("Uncomment '#define SERIAL_DEBUG' in RH_RF95.cpp for detailed debug info");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("LoRa radio init OK!");

  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb250Fd250, +13dbM
  if (!rf95.setFrequency(RF95_FREQ)) {
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.print("Set Freq to: "); Serial.println(RF95_FREQ);
  
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, 13dBm, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on

  // The default transmitter power is 13dBm, using PA_BOOST.
  // If you are using RFM95/96/97/98 modules which uses the PA_BOOST transmitter pin, then 
  // you can set transmitter powers from 5 to 23 dBm:
  rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
}

int16_t packetnum = 0;  // packet counter, we increment per xmission

void loop()
{
  delay(1000); // Wait 1 second between transmits, could also 'sleep' here!
  Serial.println("Transmitting..."); // Send a message to rf95_server
  
  char radiopacket[20] = "Hello World #      ";
  itoa(packetnum++, radiopacket+13, 10);
  Serial.print("Sending "); Serial.println(radiopacket);
  radiopacket[19] = 0;
  
  Serial.println("Sending...");
  delay(10);
  rf95.send((uint8_t *)radiopacket, 20);

  Serial.println("Waiting for packet to complete..."); 
  delay(10);
  rf95.waitPacketSent();
  // Now wait for a reply
  uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

  Serial.println("Waiting for reply...");
  if (rf95.waitAvailableTimeout(1000))
  { 
    // Should be a reply message for us now   
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
   {
      Serial.print("Got reply: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
      Serial.print("RSSI: ");
      Serial.println(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC);    
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Receive failed");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("No reply, is there a listener around?");
  }

}
```

And here are the errors

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano Every, None (ATMEGA4809)"

C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp: In member function 'virtual void RHHardwareSPI::attachInterrupt()':
C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp:49:25: error: 'virtual void SPIClassMegaAVR::attachInterrupt()' is private within this context

     SPI.attachInterrupt();
                         ^

In file included from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RadioHead.h:731:0,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RHGenericSPI.h:10,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RHHardwareSPI.h:10,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp:7:

C:\Users\jfeze\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.7\libraries\SPI\src/SPI.h:186:15: note: declared private here

   inline void attachInterrupt() { SPI0.INTCTRL |= (SPI_IE_bm); }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp: In member function 'virtual void RHHardwareSPI::detachInterrupt()':
C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp:56:25: error: 'virtual void SPIClassMegaAVR::detachInterrupt()' is private within this context

     SPI.detachInterrupt();
                         ^

In file included from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RadioHead.h:731:0,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RHGenericSPI.h:10,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead/RHHardwareSPI.h:10,
                 from C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead\RHHardwareSPI.cpp:7:

C:\Users\jfeze\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.7\libraries\SPI\src/SPI.h:187:15: note: declared private here

   inline void detachInterrupt() { SPI0.INTCTRL &= ~(SPI_IE_bm); }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Multiple libraries were found for "RH_RF95.h"
 Used: C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead
 Not used: C:\Users\jfeze\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead-master
exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Nano Every.
```

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: So far as I can tell, the library simply incompatible with your board. The functions they're trying to use are essentially commented as "don't use these" in the core(s). In the megaavr core that the Nano Every uses they were made `private:`.  For what it's worth, the functions they're used from appear to be in turn used nowhere in the project. So, I commented out the calls. However the library fails to compile owing to other differences in architecture. Basically you need a port for the megaavr core. I do not have a suggestion one for. You may not actually need RadioHead at all though.